# Configuring JaVers ID for third party objects

Tags: java, javers

I'm trying to use JaVers to store objects from a 3rd-party library that I can't change. The object definition looks something like:

```
interface TheirObject extends WithId{    
  //Other properties here...
}

interface WithId{
  String getId();
}
```

with various implementations of that interface. The ID field is not annotated in anyway.

I tried using the default JaVers configuration and got the following error:

```
JaversException MANAGED_CLASS_MAPPING_ERROR: given javaClass 'interface TheirObject' is mapped to ValueObjectType, expected EntityType
```

So I configured JaVers as follows:

```
javers = JaversBuilder.javers()
  .registerEntity(new EntityDefinition(TheirObject.class))
  .build();
```

Which gives the exception:

```
JaversException ENTITY_WITHOUT_ID: Class 'TheirObject' mapped as Entity has no Id property. Use @Id annotation to mark unique and not-null Entity identifier
```

So I tried telling it about the `id` field:

```
javers = JaversBuilder.javers()
  .withMappingStyle(MappingStyle.BEAN)
  .registerEntity(new EntityDefinition(TheirObject.class, "id"))
  .build();
```

Which gives the exception:

```
JaversException PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND: Property 'id' not found in class 'TheirObject'. If the name is correct - check annotations. Properties with @DiffIgnore or @Transient are not visible for JaVers.
```

I've tried a few different variations of `id` (e.g. `Id`, `getId`) but nothing seems to work and I haven't found the documentation very useful in working out how to proceed.

Could someone please help me configure JaVers properly so I can use it to track changes to these objects? Thanks.

**Update**: I've changed the interface above to better reflect the issue, as I'd over-simplified it to a point where my examples did actually work.

Answer (score 2):

```
JaversBuilder.javers()
            .registerEntity(new EntityDefinition(TheirObject.class, "id"))        
            .build();
```

Comment: I've tried that (see above, I had put Annotation.class rather than TheirObject.class - now corrected above). It doesn't work, with or without setting the MappingStyle.

Comment: I'm sure it works, if you could prove that there is a bug, please push a failing test case to https://github.com/javers/javers/

Comment: Ok, so I've investigated a little bit further and updated the original question as the interface wasn't quite as simple as I thought. I've confirmed this does fail under all the examples - it appears to be to do with inherited interfaces. Will look into submitting this as a bug.

Comment: For info, the issue has been reported here (with a cleaner example): https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/640